# Connecting Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

Hi I want to fetch data from *MS SQL DB* of a Remote server using Linked Servers. I have linked the servers. I am fetching data as follows.

**select * from [IP of server].[Database Name].[dbo].[Table Name]**

But I want to get [IP address] from a variable and use it.

Ex: Declare @ServIP varchar(50)

set @ServIP = 'IP of server'

select * from [@ServIP].[Database Name].[dbo].[Table Name]

I'm getting error If I use variable.

How can I do it?

Comment: Why are you using the IP address?

Comment: I'm accessing Remote Server's data. I need to mention which Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic SQL:

```
declare @ServIP varchar(50) = 'IP of server'
declare @dsql varchar(1024)
set @dsql = 'select * from ' + quotename(@ServIP) + '.DbName.dbo.TableName'
exec (@dsql)
```